# Refresh variable using system time in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using the scrip below to go to frames based on the current date, but it always seem to jump to the date I first ran the script (august 8th).

How Do I make flash update the date/variable?

```
    var augDate:Date = new Date(); 
var dayNumberaug:uint = someDate.getDay();
switch(dayNum) 
{ 
    case 0: 
        gotoAndStop(1,"August"); 
        break;    
    case 1: 
        gotoAndStop(2,"August"); 
        break; 
    case 2: 
        gotoAndStop(3,"August"); 
        break; 
    case 3: 
        gotoAndStop(4,"August"); 
        break; 
    case 4: 
        gotoAndStop(5,"August"); 
        break; 
    case 5: 
        gotoAndStop(6,"August"); 
        break; 
    case 6: 
        gotoAndStop(7,"August"); 
        break;
    case 7: 
        gotoAndStop(8,"August"); 
        break;
    case 8: 
        gotoAndStop(9,"August"); 
        break;
    case 9: 
        gotoAndStop(10,"August"); 
        break;
    case 10: 
        gotoAndStop(11,"August"); 
        break;
    case 11: 
        gotoAndStop(12,"August"); 
        break;
```

Comment: What is `someDate`? It doesn't seem to be the current date.

Comment: It actually seams to be going to the numerical month value instead of the intended day of the month. I wonder how I can fix that.....

Comment: What's with the massive `switch` you have? Have you tried something like `gotoAndStop(dayNum + 1, "August")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the manual better. `getDay()` returns day of the week, not day of the month. You are after `getDate()` function instead.

[Date class manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html)